# Turtle for loop to create image

Tags: python, for-loop, turtle-graphics

```
frame = [
    ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",
    ",,,,,,****,,,,,,,,,*,,,,,",
    ",,,,,*!!!!*,,,,,,,*¤*,,,,",
    ",,,,*!!!!!!*,,,,,,*¤¤*,,,",
    ",,,,*!!!!!!*,,,,,,*¤¤*,,,",
    ",,,*!!!!!!!!*,,,,*¤¤¤¤*,,",
    ",,*!!!!,*!!!*,,,,*¤¤%¤*,,",
    ",,*!!!!**!!!!*,,,*¤%%¤*,,",
    ",,*!!!!**!!!!*,,,,*%**,,,",
    ",,,*!!!!!!!!!!*,,,*!*,,,,",
    ",,,,**!!!!!!!!!*,*!!*,,,,",
    ",,,,,,***!!*!!!**!!*,,,,,",
    ",,,,,,,*%%*!!!!!*!!*,,,,,",
    ",,,,,,,*%%%**!!!*!*,,,,,,",
    ",,,,,,*,*%%%!!!!**,,,,,,,",
    ",,,,,,,***%%!!!**,,,,,,,,",
    ",,,,,,,,,,***!**,,,,,,,,,",
    ",,,,,,,,,,,*,!,*,,,,,,,,,",
    ",,,,,,,,,,,,****,,,,,,,,,",
    ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
]

colors = {
            ","  :  "white",
            "*"  :  "black",
            "!"  :  "orange",
            "¤"  :  "red",
            "%"  :  "yellow"
}

from mobilechelonian import Turtle
dragon = Turtle()

dragon.speed(10)
for row in frame:
    for symbol in row:
        dragon.pencolor(colors[symbol])
        dragon.forward(1)
    dragon.penup
    dragon.backward(25)
    dragon.right(90)
    dragon.forward(1)
    dragon.left(90)
```

I have this code in jupyterhub, which is suppose to draw the picture. However I only get a small white square. Also if anyone know how to readjust the screen to show the picture in full scale I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: You forgot to call the `penup` method: `dragon.penup()`. I also don't see any `dragon.pendown()` calls. You could just increase the speed, or increase the `forward` steps.

Comment: `dragon.penup` does not call the `penup` method, it merely evaluates it, then discards the result.  To call it, you have to add parentheses, i.e. `dragon.penup()`

Comment: I reformulated it and added () in dragon.penup as well at writing dragon.pendown at the very last after fragon.left(90) which gives me an even weirder result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following replaces your code (keep the data/variables before the code the same), uses the turtle module that comes with Python and adds scaling:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import tkinter as _

_.ROUND = _.BUTT

SCALE = 4

screen = Screen()
width, height = screen.window_width() / SCALE, screen.window_height() / SCALE
screen.setworldcoordinates(-width//2, -height//2, width//2, height//2)

dragon = Turtle(visible=False)
dragon.speed('fastest')
dragon.width(SCALE)

for row in frame:
    dragon.pendown()
    for symbol in row:
        dragon.pencolor(colors[symbol])
        dragon.forward(1)
    dragon.penup()
    dragon.backward(len(row))
    dragon.right(90)
    dragon.forward(1)
    dragon.left(90)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]